# Why this function stops to work with other "get element" methods than getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript, dom

i'm trying to adapt this JS form steps for my own: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps

There is a function that validates it:

```
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
```

But I want it to work only for specific field, so I added ID to the input and change the code to:

```
      y = x[currentTab].getElementById("test");
```

But then it stops to work and console shows that x[currentTab] is not a function. Please explain me, why this function works with `y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");` but stops if I change it for ID, class or name.

Comment: it returns only one element and it does not make sense to make more than one element with the same id.

Comment: `getElementById` can only be called on `document`, not on a DOM element.

Comment: W3Schools is widely known to be a poor source for documentation and learning as it often has incomplete, out of date, or just plain inaccurate information. The fact that it has you using `.getElementsByClassName()` and `.getElementsByTagName()` and old looping structures where you have to maintain the looping index yourself is evidence of this. **Stay as far away from W3Schools as you can** and instead go to: [The Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `getElementById` returns a *single* element instead of a `NodeList`. Therefore, `y[i]` no-longer works. You can remove the whole loop part because there's only one.

```
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  let valid = true;
  const tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab"); // Do you need this?
  const input = document.getElementById("test");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  if (input.value == "") {
    // add an "invalid" class to the field:
    input.className += " invalid";
    // and set the current valid status to false
    valid = false;
  }

  // ...
}
```

It should be noted that an element's ID must be unique *document-wide* so selecting by ID within a specific parent element doesn't make much sense. If each tab has an element with an ID of `test`, the HTML is invalid. You can still select a single element by *class name* with something like `tabs[currentTab].querySelector('.test');` instead.

Comment: I've tried to remove the loop and change `y[i]` to `y`, but it still shows that x is not a function. How should I fix it correctly?

Comment: Updated example; `getElementById` is only a document-level method.